# CIFilter / CIImage : BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I'm working on a "camera/photo" based application.

Application launching (sideMenu) : MainView is a normal VC in a **NavigationCTRL** with a camera button.
A tap on it pushes a new VC.
This one is normal but inside, there are these kind of things :

```
let captureSession: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var currentCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var stillCameraOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
```

So it's a custom camera view controller.
I can - this way -  have a better user experience.
Then I can take a photo (from the library, or by tapping the shot button (after putting on/off some features [Timer, HD, Flash..].

When it takes the picture, I use the **prepareForSegue** method to send the captured image to the next VC :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == Constants.Segues.CameraToFiltersSegue {
        var filterVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MYCLASSVC
        filterVC.originalImage = pictureImage
    }
}
```

And then, it pushed the new VC AND...
I got THIS MESSAGE : **BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted**

The current VC contains :

- an imageView (UIImageView) : the previous picture
- A small collection view with small (kind of thumbnail) filtered pictures from the original (**CIFilter**)

Nothing more in this view. But I have this message.
 
**What about this message?** 
**Should I do something in a different way?**

This is how I set my filters :

```
//At the top of the class
//EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2 but maybe EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES3??
static let contextFast = CIContext(EAGLContext: EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2), options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull(), kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false])

//In my static method (one of the parameter is "originalImage")
var ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
var imageFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectInstant")
filter.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let cgimg = contextFast.createCGImage(imageFilter.outputImage, fromRect: imageFilter.outputImage.extent())
return UIImage(CGImage: cgimg, scale: 1.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
```

This code runs fast!
I don't know where the message comes from.

**So please if you have any idea or something more to help?**

Answer (score 2):

If I return nil before the next line, I never have the message.

```
let cgimg = contextFast.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, fromRect: filter.outputImage.extent())
```

And if I use a normal context with the software renderer option to "true" :

```
let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: true])
```

The message disappears.
I tried to put this option into my last fastContext but nothing changed.
**So it comes from the used context**, but with a normal context, the rendered is x5 longer (maybe more). With the fast context, I never have a slow in my collectionView. I'm not even seeing a reload of the data.
But with a normal context, it's visible.

In the basic camera/photos applications, Apple has the same thing. A picture and a collectionView with thumbnail of the original picture but filtered! How do they do that? We can't even see the items loading.

Comment: Hey Julien, Did you figured it out?

Comment: on the `EAGLContext`, the `kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer` doesn't seem to have any effect at all